# Importing multiple functions from module without explicitly exporting object or named export

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

### utils/mathlib.js

```
export function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}
export function subtract(x, y) {
    return x - y;
}
```

### main.js

```
import add from "./../utils/mathlib"; //not working. but if I do default export like `export default function add(x, y)` it will work
import { add } from "./../utils/mathlib"; //working
import * as MathLib from "./../utils/mathlib"; //working
```

But I want to import all the functions available in the module with the same identifier without importing separately or through importing object. Something like the below,

```
import * from "./../utils/mathlib"
```

I should be able to use add, subtract function.

The reasoning behind this use case is, Whenever I add new functions in MathLib.js it should be available without modifying.(I took MathLib as sample use case only, in my real use case all the functions is necessary whenever I import the module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently import into the global namespace without explicit named import/exports.  It helps to prevent global namespace pollution and accidental overriding of variables in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export your functions in an default object

```
export default {
    add(x, y) {
        return x + y;
    }
    subtract(x, y) {
        return x - y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, then I have to call functions using object reference.  ie., `import MathLib from "./../utils/mathlib";`  I have to use `MathLib.add`.  Is there any other way to avoid `MathLib` object reference

Comment: I don't think. And It's good practice to have a namespace for your functions

Comment: I am defining dashboard-model namespace which exports lots of classes, In one of my data-updation logic place, I have to use all the classes without changing/modifying the import statements...so that in future If I add one class in dashboard-model namespace it should be available where ever I imported entire dashboard-model namespace . ( Dynamically I may use those classes so future addition of new classes should be availbale spontaneously)